# How to return a string in indices that are array in Laravel 7

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, helper

I would like to know how I can return a string, for any part of my request that is an array.
The request could contain any keys, so I can't hard code it.

Example of what I have done so far.

```php
$request = [
    'empresaId' => '2',
    'entidadeId' => [
        '507-2',
        '1422-2',
    ],
    'dataInicio' => '2021-05-27',
    'dataFim' => '2021-05-31',
];

$requestFiltered = Arr::where($request->all(), function($value, $key) { 
    if (!is_null($value) && ($key != '_token')) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            return collect($value)->implode(',');
        }
        return $value;
    }
});
```

This doesn't return the data in the way that I expect.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is an example of how I expect the array to be returned.

```php
[
    'empresaId' => '2',
    'entidadeId' => '507-2,1422-2',
    'dataInicio' => '2021-05-27',
    'dataFim' => '2021-05-31',
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there, you could just use `map` instead of `where`.

`where` is not used to mutate the data, it is meant to just query the data, so you are only supposed to return a Boolean in the closure.
`map` and `transform` will mutate your data.

```php
$requestFiltered = collect($request->all())->map(function ($item, $key) {
    // Ignore tokens.
    if (Str::endsWith($key, '_token')) {
        return;
    }

    // Check for arrays, then implode.
    if (is_array($item)) {
        return implode(',', $item);
    }

    return $item;
})
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the first suggestion with $request->map didn't work and returned the message "Method Illuminate\Http\Request::map does not exist."
Anyway the actual use of the function will have several internal arrays in the request. The index "entidadeId" is just an example.

Comment: @phdiasm I don't know how I was supposed to know to include additional information in this answer that you didn't provide. Silly me! I'll edit my answer with a Collection.

Comment: yes that was my mistake when asking the question, sorry.

Comment: @phdiasm It's not a mistake in asking the question. Just understand that this answer is just an example of how to incorporate this into your application. Have you seen my edit with the `collect`? That should do the trick for you.

Comment: yes, it worked. Sorry my english not very well. I expressed myself wrong, thank you so much for taking the time to answer this question.

Comment: @phdiasm No problem at all, I am glad I helped. If you have additional keys that need altering, then add them as part of that if statement.

Comment: @phdiasm I've actually updated my answer again, I'd misread your question slightly. My new answer should cover all bases for you. Hope this new one helps!

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, it's just this:

```
$requestFiltered = Arr::where($request, function($value){ 
    if(is_array($value)){
        return $value;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, with your suggestion, you continue to return the complete array, and you only need to change the values ​​of the indexes that are array to string.

Comment: I don't know what you do, but this works except that in your example `$request` is not a collection, so the call to `all()` is not necesary.